# Zoom repete várias vezes google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Tenho um `infowindow` em meu mapa. Todas as vezes que dou um `dragstart` eu fecho este `infowindow`. Meu problema, é que dou um `infowindow.open(map, marker);`, para abrir o `infowindow`.
Todas as vezes que faço isso, ele adiciona outro `infowindow` na DOM. Assim, quando faço o pedido `map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);`, ele adiciona varios zoom, de acordo com as vezes que chamei o `infowindow`.

Segue o código:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA-OlPHUh2W7LUZXVjQjjxQ8fdCWdJISmc"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
#map{width:500px; height:500px; float:left;}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var map;
var uluru = {lat:-17,lng: -47};
var infowindow = null;
function initialize(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: uluru,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: '<p><a href="#" id="zoom_mais"><b>+++++</b> </a> | <a href="#" id="zoom_menos"><b>-------</b></a></p>'
        });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: uluru,
                    draggable: true,
                    map: map,
        });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
                    if (infowindow) {
                        infowindow.close();
                        //infoWindow = null;
                    }
                    infowindow;
                    console.log('dragstart')
        });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
                    map.setCenter(this.getPosition()); // Set map center to marker position
          infowindow.open(map, marker);

        }); 

    //ZOOM
                google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
                    document.getElementById('zoom_mais').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
                        console.log(map.getZoom());
                    });
                    document.getElementById('zoom_menos').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                        map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
                        console.log(map.getZoom());         
                    });
                });

}

initialize();
```

Este exemplo em execução  [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/vcfy8cgs/).

Basta mover o `Marker` uma 4 vezes e clicar no zoom. Vocês verão que ele aumentara 4 vezes o zoom.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida exatamente?

Comment: @abcd pra que o código não se perca nos comentários, sempre adicione na pergunta, mesmo que seja linkado, assim a pergunta fica completa por si só. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, removendo esta opção:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {});
```

Na realidade, eu a adaptei a minha situação, pois todas as vezes que a chamava com um evento, era adicionado outro.